# Run a Jquery Login Form if php Login Check Fails

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I do not want to redirect to a new page if the login check fails, rather I want to stay on the page and simulate a click on the login button which would bring up a login form popup. Any ideas?

Lame attempt using php redirect which doesnt do anything desired:

```
function logincheck($redirect='')
{
if(!isset($_SESSION['duser']['id']))
{
    if($redirect)
    {
        header("Location: ".$config['site_url']."index.php? redirect=".urlencode($redirect));
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: ".$config['site_url']."index.php#login-box");

    }
    exit;
}
}
```

HTML button:

```
<li><a class="log" href="#login-box"></a></li>
```

Comment: Disregard my code. Is there anyway you can interact with jquery functions through PHP? I used to have it where I would just simply redirect to a separate login page, but I want it to be more seamless and just stay on the page and bring up a jquery pop up which I have already set, and is normally brought up through a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<head></head>`  define a javascript variable if the user is logged in or not such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" />
var logged_in = <?  if(!isset($_SESSION['duser']['id'])){ 
                       echo "FALSE";
                    }else{
                       echo "TRUE";
                    }
                ?>
</script>
```

Now when you load the page check using javascript that if logged_in is TRUE or FALSE and base on that run the javascript to pop up for login panel

Hope it helps :)